# VB.net working with Access Databases

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

I have a combo box that I have to select a name from (I already have the access data names loaded in the combo box). After the user selects a name the program should display in three separate text boxes the date of hire the id number and the salary. In addition to that if the employee works full time there is a radio button that should be checked.

I have no idea how to do this. I'm using MS Access.

Comment: This should be winforms? or Asp.net?

Comment: Is this all in MS Access (using access forms) or are you building your own user interface with something like winforms, webforms, or wpf?

Comment: You might want to give us some examples of code you have tried.  We give "Hand Ups" not "Hand Outs".  Please let us know what you have or have not tried.

Comment: yes this is a windows form and I just dont even nowhere to begin. Like I said I have not seen any examples on how to do this and I'm by no means a coder. I'm just trying to get through this class.